# Is deleting the node_module the same "npm cache clean --force"

Tags: npm, node-modules

I would like to know if there is a difference.

How to know if the node_modules is updated

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not!

force clean shouldn't be necessary in most cases and isn't recommended afaik (doesn't mean I've never done so ^^)
NPM cache lies pretty sure in .npm/ folder, definitely not in node_modules.

there is:
`npm cache verify` before complete reinstallation (might bring some insights about what exactly happened, before you delete the evidence ☺️

to update node_modules I like:
https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates

you can run:

```bash
npx npm-check-updates
```

then when something found `ncu -u` I think, but it's good documented in the repo readme. It also runs a `npm audit` automatically I think, or you should, to ensure no known (and easy to patch) vulnerabilities in use.

Comment: You can also check the option list of the .npmrc file, there are useful things, like installing peer-dependencies automatically among others. Hope this helps.